# How to use dropna on specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking for a solution to use `.dropna()` method on Pandas DataFrame for specific columns. `df.dropna(axis=1, subset=subset, inplace=True)` doesn't seem to work. Many thanks!

Comment: Can you add some data sample where solution failed?

Comment: I'm afraid not. If I use the subset I receive the KeyError

Comment: hmm, so specified column which not exist in df.columns?

Comment: No, there are the same columns

Comment: hmmm, I ask for data, because problem is not in `dropna`, but something else (and without data impossible know what is problem)

Comment: Do you want to drop `rows` or `columns`?

Comment: columns. Even if I use subset=df.columns.difference(['A','B']) I receive a KeyError

Comment: If you want to drop columns (`axis=1`), `subset` is not a list of columns, it's a list of rows.

Comment: I know, see the original post

Comment: @jezrael is right, without a sample of your dataframe, it's too difficult to solve your issue.

Comment: try `df[subset]` and if that doesn't work then columns are missing. If that works and df.dropna() still doesn't work then it's a different problem we need data for

Comment: Ok I found a workaround solution: a list comprehension empty_col=[col for col in df.columns.difference(['A']) if df.isnull().all()] and then df.drop(empty_col,axis=1,inplace=True)